# How to change or update password if registered into a site through social media

Tags: wordpress, facebook-social-plugins, user-profile

I have placed social media login/registration into my WordPress site, but I noticed that users who register through this channel cannot change/update password or their profile on my site.  It seems that my site is always dependent of these social medias and users cannot break free.
How can I enable these users to update their profiles on my platform?

Many thanks, and Happy Holidays!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function of the plugin you are using. Try using a different one. What happens to the user when you turn off the plugin? Does your plugin store email addresses in your own database?

Comment: This is the functionality of most (if not all) such social plugins.  Our DB stores the email, name, and username.

Comment: That's my point. The functionality your describing is what is intended, right? In other words, for most Login with Google password plugins, the user would go to Google to change their password, not to your sight. You'll have to develop a custom plugin to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: But if you have their email, in a sense you "have them". You can contact them outside the platform, which is the goal.